# ClickHouse: How to find databases under a certain cluster?

Tags: clickhouse

I have a clickhouse with two clusters deployed on same machines like

```
clickhouse :) select * from system.clusters;

SELECT *
FROM system.clusters 

┌─cluster────────────────────┬─shard_num─┬─shard_weight─┬─replica_num─┬─host_name─┬─host_address─┬─port─┬─is_local─┬─user────┬─default_database─┐
│ cluster-********           │         1 │            1 │           1 │ ******* │ *.*.*.* │ 9000 │        1 │ default │                  │
│ cluster-********           │         1 │            1 │           2 │ ******* │ *.*.*.* │ 9000 │        1 │ default │                  │
│ cluster-********           │         2 │            1 │           1 │ ******* │ *.*.*.* │ 9000 │        0 │ default │                  │
│ cluster-********           │         2 │            1 │           2 │ ******* │ *.*.*.* │ 9000 │        0 │ default │                  │
│ cluster-********-********* │         1 │            1 │           1 │ ******* │ *.*.*.* │ 9000 │        1 │ default │                  │
│ cluster-********-********* │         2 │            1 │           1 │ ******* │ *.*.*.* │ 9000 │        0 │ default │                  │
│ cluster-********-********* │         3 │            1 │           1 │ ******* │ *.*.*.* │ 9000 │        0 │ default │                  │
│ cluster-********-********* │         4 │            1 │           1 │ ******* │ *.*.*.* │ 9000 │        0 │ default │                  │
└────────────────────────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────────────────┴──────────────┴──────┴──────────┴─────────┴──────────────────┘

8 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.004 sec. 

clickhouse :) select * from system.databases;

SELECT *
FROM system.databases 

┌─name─────────────────┬─engine───┬─data_path───────────────────────────────────┬─metadata_path───────────────────────────────────┐
│ default              │ Ordinary │ /data/clickhouse/data/default/              │ /data/clickhouse/metadata/default/              │
│ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa │ Ordinary │ /data/clickhouse/data/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/ │ /data/clickhouse/metadata/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/ │
│ bbbbb                │ Ordinary │ /data/clickhouse/data/bbbbb/                │ /data/clickhouse/metadata/bbbbb/                │
│ system               │ Ordinary │ /data/clickhouse/data/system/               │ /data/clickhouse/metadata/system/               │
└──────────────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

4 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.001 sec.
```

Then I wanna to analyse all databases belonged to certain clusters, but table `databases` as well as `clusters` doesn't contain any information about cluster-database relations, so how to find which databases   belonged to a certain cluster, Please help if you have any idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases and tables don't belong to clusters. There is no any relation.
A table can be queried using any cluster or without a cluster.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but when we create a database,  sometimes using DDL like `on cluster` when zookeeper enabled, which don't belong to any cluster either?

Comment: `on cluster` just a helper for distributed DDLs and points where (which nodes) it needs to execute create command and does not influence on tables metadata. It's not mandatory. For example I never use `on cluster` because I have own automation.